# Removing location metadata when sharing voice memo

Tags: ios, sharing, geolocation, voice-memo

The Apple voice memo app offers to geotag recordings.

When I want to share a recording I'm not offered any sharing options at the top of the share sheet, which I normally use to strip location data from pictures and videos.

How do I strip geolocation data from audio recordings when sharing one?

iOS 14.4
iPhone 8

Comment: Metadata will not be passed on anyway if it is not sent via ICloud Drive or AirDrop. You can also manage this when sharing under "Options". (At least GPS information)

To completely delete metdata you need a computer, because I am not aware of any possibility of deleting it via the iPhone.

I do not quite understand your question

Comment: @DarwinOSX Hello. What part of it don't you understand? Edit: clarified question